# Directory Search

Tags: c#, file, directory

This is a simple question and I am sure you C# Pros know it.

If you want to grab the contents of a directory on a hard drive (local or otherwise) in a C Sharp program, how do you go about it?

Comment: It's called C#.  **Not _C Sharp_!**

Comment: @SLaks: That's true, but I've never pronounced it "C Pound".

Comment: You mean you want to make a complete copy of the directory, or you just want to find out what's in it?

Comment: It is pronounced C-Sharp, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean get a directory then it is very simple. The following code will give you a list of all the directories in a given directory and then list all the files in the directory:

```
string dir = @"C:\Users\Joe\Music";
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);

FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles();
DirectoryInfo[] directories = dirInfo.GetDirectories();

foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directories)
    Console.WriteLine(directory.Name);

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    Console.WriteLine (file.Name);
```

Comment: You should use @ strings (`@"C:\Users\Joe\Music"`)

Comment: This, http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/my_explorer.aspx, looks helpful.  I downloaded it and had a look.  It would be great if This, http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/my_explorer.aspx, looks helpful.  I downloaded it and had a look.  It would be great if this could be used to make a seperate "dialog box" (I mean "form" accoreding to C# lingo) and that what the user selects as a directory can be displayed in some fort of text field.